# disable *some* checkboxes in a column in a GXT Grid

Tags: gxt

I have a GXT Grid showing some "User" objects. One of the columns holds checkboxes (CheckboxCell) . I need to disable a checkbox for 1 particular user and leave others enabled.

I tried extending CheckboxCell class - it's useless because it does not know the context (which User is renders): it only knows about true/false state.

tried

```
GridView view = table.getView();
Element cell = view.getCell(0, 1);
cell.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

-no luck. the disabled attribute is set on the outer "td" tag instead of the child "input" element. 
tried cell.getChild..() methods - they all throw "method does not exist" exceptions.

UPDATE: I ended up creating my own CheckboxCellWhichCanBeDisabled class extending AbstractEditableCell. I'm afraid there's no other way.

Comment: disabling a widget is a view related behavior, why not use a `GridCellRenderer` to determine the enabled state for the checkboxes? you may attach the user information to the model, and render based on that info.